# How to send request body in spring-boot web client?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, webclient, spring-webflux

I'm facing some problem while sending request body in spring boot web client. Trying to send body like below:

```
val body = "{\n" +
            "\"email\":\"test@mail.com\",\n" +
            "\"id\":1\n" +
            "}"
val response = webClient.post()
    .uri( "test_uri" )
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(body))
    .exchange()
    .block()
```

Its not working. **Request body should be in JSON format.**
Please let me know where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're not setting the `"Content-Type"` request header, so you need to append `.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` to the request building part.

Answer (score 22):

The above answer is correct: Adding `application/json` in your `Content-Type` header solves the isssue. Though, In this answer, I'd like to mention that `BodyInserters.fromObject(body)` is deprecated. As of Spring Framework 5.2, it is recommended to use `BodyInserters.fromValue(body)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like following:

```
public String wcPost(){

    Map<String, String> bodyMap = new HashMap();
    bodyMap.put("key1","value1");
 

    WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("domainURL")
            .build();


    String responseSpec = client.post()
            .uri("URI")
            .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth("token if any"))
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(bodyMap))
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                if (clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
                    clientResponse.body((clientHttpResponse, context) -> {
                        return clientHttpResponse.getBody();
                    });
                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
                }
                else
                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
            })
            .block();

    return responseSpec;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding content type was not enough for me (I'm using Kotlin). Try this instead of the BodyInserters:
`.body(Mono.just(body), String::class.java)`